# Incorrect range height, was 1 but should be 3 in apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

[image]

I'm trying to use appscript aheets setvalues() to paste a row of headers into a sheet.I have:

```
var headingsArray = []
headingsArray.push(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E",  "F"]);
Logger.log(headingsArray)
sheet.getRange(3,1,3,6).setValues(headingsArray);
```

getting the error in title.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You trying to set values that are 1 row 6 columns large to a range of 3 row 6 columns. You should change your range to :

```
sheet.getRange(3,1,1,6).setValues(headingsArray);
```

since

> **setValues(values)**
>
> Sets a rectangular grid of values (must match dimensions of this
>   range).

See [getRange() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)) and [setValues() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))

Comment: Now I understand that the second 2 values are relative to the first 2 .